# 2 Way Sync between salesforce and mysql+PHP

Tags: synchronization, salesforce

we have an application which have salesforce as backend, sometimes salesforce goes down, or api access limit reached the limit, so we have to save data in mysql.

I want to 2 way sync of mysql+php with salesforce.

What can be best way of 2 way sync?

any log file for updation or flag in each database while updating and than reset this flag while sync process.

what can be best option?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to facilitate the sync is via real-time web service integration.

In Salesforce, you can setup workflow rules on the objects you want to sync to send an outbound message. Your integration code will pick up the message and then check MySQL to see whether an update is necessary. In MySQL, you can create a trigger and a UDF (in theory) to do the same thing.

In either case you'll need to create the application in the middle that listens for the messages and then executes the appropriate code to update the other system.

As an alternative to writing this code yourself, you may want to check out an integration product like [**Jitterbit**](http://www.jitterbit.com/integrate/) that can facilitate real-time and periodic feeds and syncs.